# Problem: roslaunch turtlebot_arm_bringup simple_arm_server.launch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot2, Groovy, turtlebot_arm-groovy-devel package:

After roslaunching turtlebot_arm_bringup simple_arm_server.launch:

[simple_arm_server.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_arm_bringup] nor is [turtlebot_arm_bringup] a launch file name

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154131/problem:-roslaunch-turtlebot_arm_bringup-simple_arm_server.launch/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, @Yantian_Zha : There are arm.launch and fake-arm.launch in `/turtlebot_arm_bringup/launch`. There is not the simple_arm_server.launch you say. The simple_arm_server packages seem to be put on this page ( http://wiki.ros.org/simple_arm_server ). If you want to execute it, I think that you should type

```
roslaunch simple_arm_server arm_server.launch
```

You will get more useful information on `http://wiki.ros.org/simple_arm_server` than one on`http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_arm_bringup`.
Please check it out!

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1